# Unable to pass custom values to AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to pass custom input to my lambda function (Python 3.7 runtime) in JSON format from the rule set in CloudWatch.
However I am facing difficulty accessing elements from the input correctly.

Here's what the CW rule looks like.
[image]

Here is what the lambda function is doing.

```
import sqlalchemy  # Package for accessing SQL databases via Python
import psycopg2
def lambda_handler(event,context):
    today = date.today() 
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("postgresql://some_user:userpassword@som_host/some_db") 
    con = engine.connect()
    dest_table = "dest_table"
    print(event)
    s={'upload_date': today,'data':'Daily Ingestion Data','status':event["data"]} # Error points here
    ingestion = pd.DataFrame(data = [s])
    ingestion.to_sql(dest_table, con, schema = "some_schema", if_exists = "append",index = False, method = "multi")
```

When I test the event with default test event values, the `print(event)` statement prints the default test values ("key1":"value1") but the syntax for adding data to the database `ingestion.to_sql()` i.e the payload from input `"Testing Input Data"` is inserted to the database successfully.

However the lambda function still shows an error while running the function at `event["data"]` as Key error.

1) Am I accessing the Constant JSON input the right way?

2) If not then why is the data still being ingested as the way it is intended despite throwing an error at that line of code

3) The data is ingested when the function is triggered as per the schedule expression. When I test the event it shows an error with the Key. Is it the test event which is not similar to the actual input which is causing this error?

There is alot of documentation and articles on how to take input but I could not find anything that shows how to access the input inside the function. I have been stuck at this point for a while and it frustrates me that why is this not documented anywhere. 
Would really appreciate if someone could give me some clarity to this process.
Thanks in advance

Edit:
Image of the monitoring Logs:

[image]

[image]

> [ERROR] KeyError: 'data' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/test.py"

Comment: It looks correct to me. What is the exact error message

Comment: `event["data"]` is the correct way of accessing `Test Input Data`. There shouldn't be any error at the line you point, unless your screenshot shows incorrect `Constant` string passed to the function.

Comment: I have added Images from the logs in the edit

Comment: Are you running the function with the **Test** button in the Lambda console, or is it being triggered by the CloudWatch schedule?

Comment: On your screenshots there no such error as ` KeyError: 'data' `. Also have you increased timeout for your lambda? Seems as you are hitting the default time of 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am writing this answer based on the comments. 
The syntax that was originally written is valid and I am able to access the data correctly. There was a need to implement a timeout as the function was constantly hitting that threshold followed by some change in the iteration.